# changing state in certain/selected array when doing array mapping

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, array-map

What is the right way to use state in array mapping

I would like to mapping an array of data. On each item, I have a Menu and MenuItem from material-ui. I handle the method to open the Menu by changing the state. But, if I only use one state, then all the menu will opened because to open the menu on each array I only use this.state.open. Do you know how to make the Menu only open on the desire array? Thank you for any help.

here is what I've made so far.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu'
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem'

const dataMap = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "john"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Doe"
    }
]

export default class MyComponent extends Component {

    state = {
        open: false
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            open: !this.state.open
        })
    }

    render() {
        const mapResult = dataMap.map((item, index) => {
            const id = item.id;
            const name = item.name;
            return <span key={index}>
                {name}
                <Menu
                    open={this.state.open}
                >
                    <MenuItem id={id}>First</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem id={id}>Second</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem id={id}>Third</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </span>
        })
        return (
            <div>
                {mapResult}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Expected result:
Only one Menu open at a time in the selected index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the data id as state instead of a boolean (eg. `openedMenuId`)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu'
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem'

const dataMap = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "john"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Doe"
    }
]

export default class MyComponent extends Component {

    state = {
        openedMenuId: null
    }

    handleClick(newOpenedMenuId) {
        this.setState({
            openedMenuId: newOpenedMenuId
        })
    }

    render() {
        const mapResult = dataMap.map((item, index) => {
            const id = item.id;
            const name = item.name;
            return <span key={index}>
                {name}
                <Menu
                    open={this.state.openedMenuId === item.id}
                >
                    <MenuItem id={id}>First</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem id={id}>Second</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem id={id}>Third</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </span>
        })
        return (
            <div>
                {mapResult}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```